# Can I add attributes to 'window' object in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript

Can I add any attribute to 'window' object in Angular? Some thing like:

```
window.attr = "my_value"
```

I try tu use the object windows bat have the error:

> Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: To ways to do it
1. `window['attr']`
2. `declare var window: any;` on top of the file

Answer (score 2):

Try casting window to `any` like

```
(window as any).attr = "my_value"
```

Or define type on the top of the component after your imports

```
declare var window: any;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
 Window["attr"] = "my_value";
```